# error: expected unqualified-id before 'switch'

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm making a code where the users input date, month, year and the program can identify if its a leap year or not but i ran into trouble with the error saying "expected unqualified-id before 'switch' ". What is happening with my code? I can't figure out the issue. this is the line im having problems with "switch(Month)". can someone help me please.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
// declaring
int Day = 0;
int Month = 0;
int Year = 0;
bool leapYear (int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // outputting messages to the user
    cout << "Lets check your dates shall we?" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter in a two(2) digit number for the month." << endl;
    cin >> Month;
    cout << "Please enter in a two(2) digit number for the day." << endl;
    cin >> Day;
    cout << "Please enter in a four(4) digit number for the year." << endl;
    cin >> Year;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
switch(Month)
{
       case 1:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "January" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 2:
            if (Day == 1 ... 28)
               cout << "February" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            else if (Day == 29)
               leapYear(Day);  
            break;
       case 3:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "March" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 4:
            if (Day == 1 ... 30)
               cout << "April" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 5:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "May" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 6:
            if (Day == 1 ... 30)
               cout << "June" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 7:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "July" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 8:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "August" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 9:
            if (Day == 1 ... 30)
               cout << "September" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 10:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "October" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 11:
            if (Day == 1 ... 30)
               cout << "November" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
       case 12:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)
               cout << "December" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
}
```

Comment: Your switch statement needs to be inside of the main function.

Comment: The order of your code lines seems to be *seriously* jumbled up! The whole `switch` block should, presumably, be between the last `cin` and the `system` call.

Comment: What do you expect `if (Day == 1 ... 31)` to do? It's going to be another compiler error once you fix your current one.

Comment: so should i delete that line and put it between cin and system?

Comment: im new to this coding thing, this is an activity at school. to be passed on sunday. and i still dont know how to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` statement can't be in the global scope. You need to put it inside a function, like the `main()` function. Right after `cin >> Year;` seems to be the correct place for it.

Also, the range comparisons you do are not valid C++:

```
       case 1:
            if (Day == 1 ... 31)   // ERROR
               cout << "January" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
```

You can do something similar by including `<algorithm>` and then use [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp):

```
       case 1:
            if ( &Day == &std::clamp(Day, 1, 31) )
               cout << "January" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
            break;
```

`std::clamp` will here return a reference to `Day` if it's within the range and by comparing the address of what is returned with the address of `Day` you can check if it's within the range.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5P4oK3) - Note that you also miss the implementation for `bool leapYear (int);`. I made a function that just returns `false` so you need to add your own implementation for it.

When you've implemented the `leapYear(int);` function, consider changing the `case` for February:

```
        case 2:
                if ( &Day == &std::clamp(Day, 1, 28 + leapYear(Year)) )
                cout << "February" << Day << "th," << Year << "," << endl;
                break;
```

If `std::clamp` isn't available for some reason, you can easily create a range checking function:

```
bool in_range(int value, int low, int high) {
    return low <= value && value <= high;
}
```

which will change the usage slightly:

```
       case 1:
            if ( in_range(Day, 1, 31) )
```

Comment: Nice catch! I think gcc allows this as an extension. `case 1 ... 3:`, but not in a comparison/expression.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thanks! Cool. I didn't know about that. You got my vote before I noticed the range error myself. :)

Comment: i added the std::clamp sir and my new problem now is this "[Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token"

Comment: @TaekWondo Did you look at the demo ?

Comment: thank you for all of your answers, i think im goin to start from scratch again, make a simpler code.

Comment: @TaekWondo You are welcome. Rewriting is good when you've noticed that some parts may be simplified, so, good thinking!

Comment: (this is what our teacher wanted us to make, i guess i made a complicated code and made it hard for my self. XD) Create a simple program that ask the user to input month and year using switch
statement. The program will identify if the month entered by the user has 30 or 31 days except
February. In February, the program must identify if the year inputted by the user is leap year or
not, if leap year the February has 29 days, if not it has 28 days.

Comment: @TaekWondo Yes, that's the change I proposed at the bottom in my answer. The February `clamp` will have 28 days for normal years and 29 days for leap years. That will work since the `bool` returned by the `bool leapYear(int);` function will be promoted to integer `0` or `1`. `0` for normal years and `1` for leap years.

Comment: i will rewrite everything and add the february clamp sir.

Comment: The program can be written in any number of ways. Just get it working first - then take a look at it to see if there's some pattern to some of the things your do that may be simplified. It may be possible to keep an array of month names and their ranges so that you don't need a big `switch` for example (but then again, the assignment mentioned that you should use a `switch` specifically so that may not be acceptable).

Comment: ill try to get it working tomorrow sir, its almost 10 p.m from where i am. thanks again for the help sir.

Answer (score 1):

`switch(Month)` is outside the body of `main` (at global scope), move the `switch` one line before `system("PAUSE");`:

```
cin >> Year;

switch(Month)
{
   ...
}

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: can i ask you a question again sir?

Comment: i got my code to work, but i dont know how to add the switch statement.

Comment: Switch from `if (Day == 1 ... 31)` to `if (day >= 1 && day <= 31)` in all your `case`s

Comment: i posted my new code, can you please take a look at it. how do i add the switch statement on it?

Comment: I don't get you, you don't need the month in order to know if a year is leap, why do you need a `switch`?

Comment: (this is what our teacher wanted us to make) Create a simple program that ask the user to input month and year using switch statement. The program will identify if the month entered by the user has 30 or 31 days except February. In February, the program must identify if the year inputted by the user is leap year or not, if leap year the February has 29 days, if not it has 28 days.

Comment: what is that link sir, i cant open it.

Comment: How you can't open? is a link to ideone, ok, I paste it in another site: https://pastebin.com/gj4qa4GP

Comment: Ok, you are welcome, please, next time don't do this (replace the question with a new unrelated one)  it invalidates all the answers, I roolback your edit.

Comment: im sorry i didnt know. wont happen again. thanks again sir